En un select de html, trabajando con Spring, ¿cómo puedo poner una opción por defecto?
Estoy trabajando con Java y Spring.
Tengo un select que dinámicamente carga unos options de un formulario. Sé que hay th:selected para poner una opción por defecto, pero eso no me vale, ya que no siempre quiero esa opción por defecto.
Cuando el formulario se carga por primera vez, el th:field estará a null, así que quiero que se cargue esa opción por defecto. Cuando el usuario guarde un borrador de ese formulario y se vuelva a cargar el formulario debería aparecer la opción que haya guardado el usuario.
¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?
¡Gracias de antemano!
Este sería el código del select. He borrado algunas partes por confidencialidad.


Buenas, bienvenido al sitio, ¿le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? ¿Puedes incluir la parte de tu código donde construyes ese select? Supongo que tienes algún controlador que recupera esas opciones de la base de datos y cuál de ellas exactamente ha guardado el usuario y de alguna forma le pasa esa información a la vista. Debería incluir la parte de tu código donde se realiza esa transferencia de info (CONTROLADOR - VISTA).

¿ya intentaste ponerle valor esde tu controlador?

Buenas, muchas gracias por vuestra contestación. El caso es que es una duda de mi trabajo y por temas de confidencialidad no puedo mostrar código. Había pensado hacerlo desde el controlador o desde JS, pero mi jefe me ha comentado que lo hiciera desde el HTML. He visto que no se puede hacer un condicional en un th:field y con el th:selected tampoco es válido, así que ando un poco perdido..hehe.
